# setInterval based on ajax result or promise state

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, timer, setinterval

I need to send an ajax request with an interval of 5s

```js
const asyncF = async () => { await /* some ajax stuff */ }

asyncF(); // fire off an ajax request first
setInterval(() => { // start an interval
  asyncF();
}, 5 * 1000);
```

Normally the `asyncF` should succeed within 5s, so 5s between sucessive starts are normally ok and simple, but I want to make sure when next asyncF fires, the previous one has succeeded. If the previous one didn't succeed, then start a new interval whenever previous one succeeds

- if `asyncF` takes less than 5s to succeed, all is good!
- if `asyncF` takes more than 5s to succeed, I need to clear the interval and start a new interval whenever `asyncF` succeeds
- if `asyncF` fails within 5s, I also need to immediately call it again and set a new interval

I came up with this naive idea which kind of solves the problem

```js
let flag = true; // global variable flag
const asyncF = async () => {
 await /* some ajax stuff */
 flag = true;
}

try {
  asyncF();
  setTimer();
} catch {
  asyncF();
  setTimer();
}

function setTimer() {
  let timer = setInterval(() => {
    if (flag) {
      asyncF();
    } else {
      clearInterval(timer);
      timer = setTimer();
    }
  }, 5 * 1000);
  return timer;
}
```

However with this method, if `asyncF` takes more than 5s to succeed, the timer start counting **before `asyncF` succeeds**

Is there any mature and graceful solution to solve the problem?

Comment: Do you want 5s between sucessive _starts_ or 5s after the previous call _finishes_?

Comment: To clarify, I want 5s between sucessive starts

Comment: Got that but then "start the new interval whenever asyncF succeeds" - so if `asyncF` takes 6 seconds you start a new interval so it starts again 5 seconds later (so 11 seconds between starts in this instance)?

Comment: Well, normally the `asyncF` should succeed within 5s, so 5s between sucessive starts are normally ok and simple, but I want to make sure when next `asyncF` fires, the previous one has succeeded. If the previous one didn't succeed, then start a new interval whenever previous one succeeds(what a loop

Comment: @Jamiec I have edited the question to make it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to do this not with a `setInterval` and have to work out when to cancel/restart it, but with a `setTimeout`.

The idea is that you set a timer for 5 seconds, and if the previous function has finished you recall the function. If the timeout has been reached while the function is executing you execute it immediately, and same goes for if an error occurs.

```
async function limitedFunction(){
  let isRunning = true;
  let timeoutReached = false;
  setTimeout( () => {
    timeoutReached = true;
    if(!isRunning)
      limitedFunction();
  },5000);
  
  try{
    await asyncF();
    isRunning = false;
    if(timeoutReached)
      limitedFunction();
  } 
  catch {
    limitedFunction();
  }  
}
```

In the example below I have mocked out your `asyncF` function whereby it randomly suceeds or fails (80% chance of success) and has a random delay which sometimes goes over 5 seconds. However this is no different from your ajax-based async function. It would work exactly the same way!

You should see that

- When the function succeeds in <5s it waits 5s since the original start to fire again
- When the function succeeds in >5s it starts again immediately
- When the function fails it starts again immediately.

Hopefully this matches your requirements

```js
async function asyncF(){
  
  const delay = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve,ms))
  
  const rndFunc = Math.random();
  const rndTime = Math.floor((Math.random() * 7) + 1);
  
  if(rndFunc < 0.8){
    console.log(`asyncF will succeed in ${rndTime}s`)
    await delay(rndTime*1000)
  }
  else{
    console.log(`asyncF will fail in ${rndTime}s`);
    await delay(rndTime*1000)
    throw "I failed"
  }  
}

async function limitedFunction(){
  let isRunning = true;
  let timeoutReached = false;
  setTimeout( () => {
    timeoutReached = true;
    if(!isRunning)
      limitedFunction();
  },5000);
  
  try{
    await asyncF();
    isRunning = false;
    if(timeoutReached)
      limitedFunction();
  } 
  catch {
    limitedFunction();
  }  
}

limitedFunction()
```

Comment: Nice try to use `setTimeout` to simulate `setInterval`！I wonder if there is a pattern on when to use `setTimeout` to simulate `setInterval`. I find it hard and inflexible to handle complex timer-based problems using `setInterval`

Comment: @crazyones110 me too, which is why I would avoid it in this example. Also you dont really have a 5 second interval, you have a sometimes-5-second-sometimes-straight-away interval - which is pretty hard to achieve with `setInterval` and very easy with `setTimeout`

Comment: I wonder if there is some best practice about this technique?

Comment: @crazyones110 I doubt it. Javascript is a pretty open language with lots of possible implementations